# Sum of angles in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request

Given three vectors $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard scalar product the follwing is true
$$\angle(v_1,v_2)+\angle(v_2,v_3)\geq \angle(v_1,v_3).$$

It tried to substitute $\angle(v_1,v_2) = cos^{-1}\frac{v_1 \cdot v_2}{\Vert v_1 \Vert \Vert v_2 \Vert}$ but I could not show the resulting inequality. What is the name of the inequality and do you know reference that one can cite in an article?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest "triangle inequality in spherical geometry".

Comment: Any reference for this?

Comment: I don't find a reference for this either!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the problem to $\mathbb{R}^3$, and there wlog v2=(0,0,1)
then one gets an easy to prove inequality if one writes everything in polar coordinates.